# From AWS SDK, how to I get the current logged in username (or IAM user)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I'm using the Ruby SDK (V2), but I guess my question is more general than the specific implementation as I couldn't find an answer in any of the SDKs.

How do I get the username (and/or IAM user) that my session currently belongs to?

I let the SDK run its default behaviour for choosing credentials (ENV vars, then 'default' profile or other if specified and then machine role). Then I initialize my client and run commands. I'd like to know 'who is running the commands'. I expect to get the AWS username and if the chosen credentials were of an IAM user in it, then this username too.

Any ideas?
The best I got so far was that after I build a `Client` object, I can query it's actual `config` and get `Credentials`. But that only gives me what credentials were chosen (i.e. `SharedCredentials profile='default'` vs. `Credentials key=.. secret=..`) and doesn't tell me who is the username behind it.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Be careful with your terminology -- interactions with the AWS APIs are all over HTTP, and are sessionless and stateless, so there's not really a concept of the currently "logged in" user, or a "session."

However, for a given set of credentials, you can fetch the attributes of the "current" user (the user whose credentials you're using) from `Aws::IAM::CurrentUser`.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/IAM/CurrentUser.html

Apologies for the lack of an example -- I am unfamiliar with Ruby in general -- but found this based on what I knew could be done with the direct query APIs and command line client with `aws iam get-user`.  The available attributes are all the same: `user_name`, `password_last_used`, `create_date`, `user_id`, `path`, and `arn`... so I suspect this is what you're looking for.

From the [Query API docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetUser.html):

> it defaults to the user making the request

Comment: Agree about the terminology. Indeed I meant the user whose credentials I'm using. Thanks about that, that gives me almost everything. I'll just add that if the user doesn't have the IAM:GetUser permission, we'll get an exception, but surprisingly enough, the exception message contains the ARN of the requesting user. Ugly, but works. Here is a thread that gives a code example to parse it: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=108012

Comment: Can someone give a similar link for java SDK? I tried to retrace in java doc but couldn't get it.

Comment: It may not work, if the user doesn't have permissions to call IAM: ```An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetUser operation: User: arn:aws:iam::11111111111:user/username is not authorized to perform: iam:GetUser on resource: user username because no identity-based policy allows the iam:GetUser action```

Answer (score 12):

STS (Security Token Service) provides an API for this:

`GetCallerIdentity` Returns details about the IAM identity whose credentials are used to call the API.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html

Sample console output:

```
% aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "AIDAREDCATEDXFGN",
    "Account": "071111111115",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::071111111115:user/username"
}
```

Comment: This is the most correct answer. And it works even if the user doesn't have permissions to call IAM actions.

Comment: As the author of the other answer, I agree that this solution is better.  STS GetCallerIdentity is not subject to any permissions.